# Calculating 3D coordinate with trigonometry in lua

Tags: lua

I want to calculate a 3D position using lua, there's some built in functions and **I have code to move the player forwards, but I want to move the player backwards**.

```
local x, y, z = getElementPosition ( localPlayer ) 
local r = getPedRotation ( localPlayer ) 
x = x - math.sin ( math.rad ( r ) ) * 1.5 
y = y + math.cos ( math.rad ( r ) ) * 1.5 
setElementPosition ( localPlayer, x, y, z ) 
setElementRotation ( localPlayer, 0, 0, r  )
```

To explain the above, **getElementPosition returns 3 values, x, y and z**...  **getPedRotation returns one, the rotation of the ped (in this case the player)** and **localPlayer is the player**, the rest is pretty clear, **setElementPosition sets the players position**, same for rotation...

So in my mind the following should work to make the player move back

```
local x, y, z = getElementPosition ( localPlayer ) 
local r = getPedRotation ( localPlayer ) 
x = x + math.sin ( math.rad ( r ) ) * 1.5
y = y - math.cos ( math.rad ( r ) ) * 1.5 
setElementPosition ( localPlayer, x, y, z ) 
setElementRotation ( localPlayer, 0, 0, r  )
```

It doesn't work unfortunately, and no matter if I add/subtract 180º to "r" it still does the same, the script is for MTA San Andreas, so if anyone can see where I've went wrong would be nice of you to tell me, was never good at math, but learning lots by doing little things like this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `...; local _, _, r = getElementRotation(localPlayer); ...; setElementRotation(localPlayer,0,0,r,"default",true)`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Will not work, the way they are using LUA they have eliminated the need for semicolons (sorry if it's not the right word but only done LUA on this).  I have somehow made it work, I think it was just because I was using a timer and it checked if the players key was down every 50ms, thanks anyway.